# Amalgamation involving an alloy

Tags: alloy, mercury

Just curious, would mercury form an amalgam with gold that is already part of an alloy, i.e a gold platinum alloy?

Comment: related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/67387/102629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a traditional method of gold purification from platinum group metals.